# What differences do I have to take into account if using MySQL Transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

I was recently told that I should use transactions in my application as they can help run code quicker and prevent MySQL code from executing before a whole page has loaded (e.g. if someone is just refreshing on my page and the whole page doesn't load, no MySQL calls will start and it reduces load on the server.)

I'm wondering if I wanted to switch my site to transactions, how difficult would this be, and what changes would I have to make?

Also, I'm using PDO as opposed to `mysql_*`, if that would make any difference?

Comment: Code run quicker? Since when?

Comment: Beware of what this person tells you from here on out. =)

Comment: Ya. Don't believe anything this guy tells you anymore. This just isn't true.

Comment: Well, not necessarily quicker as it is simply the fact that it doesn't put as much load on the server. I didn't explain that right. In other words: That was me who misinterpreted transactions, not him. Trust me, he's very careful about what he tells people. ;)

Comment: Why do you want the query to execute only if the page loads? If you are using PHP for example, just the request itself will execute the script and it won't quit even if the user aborts the connection.

Comment: Nice thinking George. Simply to relieve all the stress on the DB for constant refreshing (think DDOS attacks.)

Comment: I see. So do you use javascript's onLoad event to issue the request?

Comment: The commit request? No. The idea being that the script would never get the the query("COMMIT") line, but as you said, PHP will continue interpreting the code whether a user is still viewing the file or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions, in web applications, are generally used for [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) and for [Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation).

They don't "*prevent MySQL code from executing before a whole page has loaded*" : MySQL queries are still executed when you call `mysql_query` *(or any equivalent using PDO or `mysqli_*`)*. But they will all be "cancelled" if you do not commit the transaction.

They also don't have that much to do with helping "*run code quicker*" ; even if they can sometimes have that effect, it's only because if you don't explicitly use a transaction for a group of queries *(resulting in only one transaction)*, MySQL will implicitly use one transaction for each query *(resulting in several transactions, which might put some additionnal load on the DB server)*

Notes :

- of course, this is using a DB engine that supports transactions -- like InnoDB.
- for the "quicker" point, I've seen it a couple of times ; but it was in special situations, where I needed speed more than ACID -- or maybe it was just a matter of load on the server (which means if you want to go down that path, you have to profile, to know what's faster in your specific case ! )

Using PDO, `mysql_*`, or `mysqli_*` shouldn't make much of a difference, here -- even if it's recommended not to use `mysql_*` *(old, and doesn't support some features of MySQL >= 4.1, such as prepared statements)*.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using PDO, I just wanted to make sure as many people still use `mysql_*`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're using transactions *already* when you use an RDBMS.  However, unless you're  *explicit* about when transactions start and finish, you're implicitly allowing each SQL statement to start and finish a separate transaction.  This is also called "auto-commit."

Transactions are a good tool for making logical sets of changes by multiple SQL statements, so you can commit or rollback the whole set of changes as a unit, and ensure your changes leave the database in a consistent state.  Transactions are not primarily intended to improve performance.

There's a small overhead to start and finish any transaction.  This is magnified if you use implicit transactions for high-volume changes, incurring the overhead for every statement.  For instance this becomes significant if you run thousands of `INSERT` statements to perform a bulk data load, each `INSERT` implicitly in a separate transaction.  In other cases, the performance benefit of using transactions versus not using transactions is trivial, especially in a language like PHP that has a "share-nothing" architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions provide ACID, not make your "code quicker".

If anything, they'll make it slower. I suggest you do more research on transactions before jumping to such a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the transactional speed of MySQL but in SQLite it's generally faster to use transactions, I believe however that in MySQL they should slow you down.

Regarding the changes you need to make, well... Almost none:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
$result = [execution of several queries]
if $result fails -> ROLLBACK, else COMMIT
```

I also suggest you use PDO over mysqli or mysql.

Comment: mysqlnd is not a php extension.